# Adding unique classes to similar class groups with jQuery

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, sidebar

I'm trying to make collapsing sidebar of product categories. by using woocommerce product categories widget and a bit of code (without coding the sidebar showing all the categories & sub-categories one above another). I achieved to make a collapsing sidebar but when I click one main category - all the categories opened at once and all subcategories appear.

I didn't find a way to give each sub-category group a unique class using jQuery only - all by woocommerce default has calls called "children".

```js
(function($) {  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li.cat-item-22").click(function() {
            $('ul.children').slideToggle();
        });
    
        $("li.cat-item-29").click(function() {
            $('ul.children').slideToggle();
        });
    
        $("li.cat-item-30").click(function() {
            $('ul.children').slideToggle();
        });
    
        $("li.cat-item-40").click(function() {
            $('ul.children').slideToggle();
        });
    
        $("li.cat-item-43").click(function() {
            $('ul.children').slideToggle();
        });
    
        $("li.cat-item-55").click(function() {
            $('ul.children').slideToggle();
        });
     
        $("li.cat-item-61").click(function() {
            $('ul.children').slideToggle();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use attribute selector to get your object

```
$("li[class^='cat-item-'],li[class*='cat-item-']")
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

And then use $(this) to refer to you current object with click event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("li[class^='cat-item-'],li[class*='cat-item-']").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul.children').slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.children { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="cat-item-22">
    Test in li.cat-item-22
    <ul class="children">
      <li>Test in ul.children</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="cat-item-24">
    Test in li.cat-item-24
    <ul class="children">
      <li>Test in ul.children</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked with the function below - that way i could give each 'children' class a unique id that solved my problem.

```
(function($){

$('ul.children').each(function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g){
$(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('class')+a)
})
console.log($('body').html());
```